# Acessar variável de array

Tags: ios, swift

Estou com o seguinte problema, tem um array que é meu picker, e tenho uma função que sabe a posição do meu picker, logo gostaria de comparar para saber qual texto esta naquela posição , ou seja saber o texto que esta na posição do array :

```
var pickerDataSource = ["OPC A", "OPC B", "OPC C", "OPC D"];
func x () {labelDaPosicao = self.pickerDataSource[row] }
```

Lembrando que o `row` é dado pela função, como posso resolver isto?

Comment: http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-uipickerview-example-using-swift/

Comment: amigo ja tinha visto este tutorial, porem não e isto que estou precisando, a questao é como acessar o aray, como : array[0] ou array[variavel_rows] obrigado

Comment: Resolvi o problema, por algum bug no xcode depois de reiniciar funcionou...
Obrigado

Comment: @AugustoFurlan se sabes qual era o bug podes juntar uma resposta completa, com solução e explicação para ser útil a outros que possam ter o mesmo problema. Isso seria o ideal :)

Comment: Augusto, este site funciona como a Wikipedia. Já viu alguém colocar *"Oi galera, vamos falar de Tal Assunto"* lá? Pois é, aqui é mesma coisa, saudações são consideradas ruído, por favor, foco no problema. Pode socializar a vontade no [chat].

Comment: @brasofilo até o "estou com o seguinte problema" é ruído, afinal se não estivesse, não estaria perguntando :)

Comment: Ok , desculpe , apenas tentei ser educado ....

Comment: Sem problema, Augusto. É só porquê vi que já tinham removido isso em perguntas anteriores suas, então achei melhor dar o toque e assim poupar esse trabalho dos editores. Quando alguém edita seu post, é legal dar uma conferida no histórico para ver que melhorias fazem. Valeu!